# Drawing fancy arrows in Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, visualization

Here is a figure I clipped from [Lorena A. Barba group](http://lorenabarba.com/news/new-paper-published-cise-journal/)
http://i4.tietuku.com/229231358fba454f.png

I just curious about the red arrow mixing with white dot shown on the figure.

Can matplotlib has the function to draw this kind of arrow(I think it's "canyon style")

Maybe this one is more clear:

http://i4.tietuku.com/88a340147ca388c6.png

*clipped from  James Bagrow's lab [here](http://bagrow.com/teaching/NetSci2012school_Bagrow.pdf)*

Comment: oh finally i can see it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not know if it's possible. And looking at the Gallery (http://matplotlib.org/gallery.html), it does not seem easily available.

But maybe what `plt.xkcd()` does provides some clue on how to go about.

Here is the source code of `pyplot.py`: https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/12e08785fcb0b1a6bce946de689a3f84b67731f7/lib/matplotlib/pyplot.py

calling `plt.xkcd()` just change some rcParams and namely `'path.sketch'` gives the randomness of the line. So, with similar approach you could experiment with those rcParams to come up with a brush stroke like style...

There are a bunch of parameters to play with. (Customizing matplotlib, http://matplotlib.org/users/customizing.html)